# Links to tables using hypreref/hypcap over-shoots table

Tags: hyperref

I self-taught myself everything from this community so preemptive thank you to all.

I am using a slightly hacked version of sphinx to generate my tex files and then use XeLaTex to compile it. I use it to make out-standing reports that have taught me loads of important typographical elements I just did not appreciate otherwise.

That said, I cannot for the life of me get links to tables to actually arrive at the table in the viewing software. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Formatting of colours ______________________________________________________
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{ClrRed}{RGB}{          255,  0, 0}


% Formatting of links ________________________________________________________
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[all]{hypcap}


% Formatting of tables _______________________________________________________
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{.75ex}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Summary}

Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum eu, tincidunt sit amet, laoreet
vitae, arcu. Aenean faucibus pede eu ante. Praesent enim
\hyperref[Ch01Tab0101]{Table} \ref{Ch01Tab0101}.
sapien mattis porttitor. Vestibulum porttitor. Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis eu
lacus commodo facilisis. Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim interdum, justo
lectus sagittis dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus dui. Mauris tempor ligula
sed lacus. Duis cursus enim ut augue. Cras ac magna. Cras nulla. Nulla egestas.
Curabitur a leo. Quisque egestas wisi eget nunc. Nam feugiat lacus vel est.
Curabitur consectetuer.

\lipsum[4-6]


\lipsum[14-16]


\begin{table}[!htbp]

\small

%\capstart - Thanks Ulrike, I have taken this command out.

\begin{center}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.08\textwidth}
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.18\textwidth}
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.18\textwidth}
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.18\textwidth}
>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.12\textwidth}}

\arrayrulecolor{ClrRed}
\toprule
\textbf{\relax
Year
\unskip}\relax &\textbf{\relax
Gross
\unskip}\relax &\textbf{\relax
Net
\unskip}\relax &\textbf{\relax
Random
\unskip}\relax &\textbf{\relax
Total {[}daily{]}
\unskip}\relax \\
\midrule
2017 & 446 & 431 & 4956 & 78 \\
2018 & 260 & 247 & 3025  & 46 \\
2019 & 60 & 57 &  760 & 11 \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption[Annualised Data]{Annualised Data.}\phantomsection\label{\detokenize{Ch01Tab0101}}

\end{table}


\lipsum[2-4]


\end{document}
```

If you click the link on the second line of the body text "Table 1.1" it take you to the third page (more or less depending on your software).

I don't mind a solution that has the table name above a table. But from the Q&A on similar topics, I have played about with \capstart a lot and can't get it to work.

I suspect the problem is me, but usually with trial and error with the Tex solutions I get there, in this case I can't.

Thanks!

**Update No. 1:**
I am still having issues with this even when I take out spurious and conflicting lines out. The only way this works is if I view the final pdf in Safari. Everything else over-shoots the table (I've tested it on Mac, Win & linux software).

Let me attach a composite image with what works and what doesn't. Note my comments are in light blue where I try and explain what is going on.

[image: Composite image of the Minimum (Not?) Working Example as viewed with different software post-click of hyperlink.]

Comment: You are using hypcap with the option `all`. This means that \capstart is inserted automatically. Remove your manual \capstart, it only confuse the links.

Comment: Hi Ulrike, I have tried to tidy up my code as per your suggestion but for most apps the end result is the same. Is the hyperlinking of tables normally like this? In the image attached, there are 3 screenshots. The lower one is what I expect but I always get the middle one.

Comment: Remove also the stray \phantomsection.

Comment: That was it! Amazing 2 years of grief solved. Thanks so very much.